# How ChromeCast Communicate with reciever app and sender App?

Tags: chromecast

As we know we send and receive message in json form from send app to receiver app. what is the proper channel for sending and receiving message and what role ChromeCast play in whole picture?

Answer (score 0):

Senders and receivers are establishing a socket connection and communicate via IPC.  While it's true that this communication is in JSON format, you will likely neither generate that data yourself nor care about the 'how' or 'channels' of it - in fact, you are not even allowed to following the terms of service by Google.

Instead, you have the SDK handle that for you one both the sender and receiver site.

Communication is done in the form of defined [Messages](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/messages) that implement a schema and contain objects - most notably for media playback that is [MediaInformation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/core_features#custom-messages). 
Most of those objects that are passed between sender and receiver have a `customData` property that you can use to add self-defined payload in JSON format.

If you want to implement your own features you can implement [custom messages](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/core_features#custom-messages).